# How to access the new tab using Chrome Extensions API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm trying to refresh the 'new tab' tab containing my extension's logic, whenever the `storageChange` array got bigger. If it was active tab that I wanted to refresh, I would just access tabs[0], specifying in query: `active: true`. But when I `console.log(tabs)`, I get an array, yes, but without the 'new tab' tab.

In `update-grid.js` (a background script file):

```
// ...

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
    for (key in changes) {
        var storageChange = changes[key];
        console.log('Storage key "%s" in namespace "%s" changed. ' +
                                'Old value was "%s", new value is "%s".',
                                key,
                                namespace,
                                storageChange.oldValue,
                                storageChange.newValue);

        if (storageChange.oldValue < storageChange.newValue) {

            //  This is how i would refresh it if it was active tab
            chrome.tabs.query({
                active: true,
                currentWindow: true
            }, function (tabs) {
                console.log(tabs); // prints all tabs but the new tab.
                chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {
                    url: tabs[0].url
                });
            });

        } 

    }

}); // end onChanged
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Fishky",
  "description": "Learn new words every day.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {"19" : "assets/fishky_03_19.png",
    "38" : "assets/fishky_03_38.png"},
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "icons": {
    "16" : "assets/fishky_03_19.png",
    "64" : "assets/fishky_03_64.png",
    "128": "assets/fishky_03_128.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js",
      "update-grid.js"

    ]
  },

"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "css": [
      "styles/lightbox.css",
      "styles/bottomLightbox.css"
    ]
  }
],

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus",
    "storage"

  ],

   "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "words-grid.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Chrome are you on, 60 or 61?

Comment: When you check, it automatically updates, so in a minute I'll be on 61 :)

Comment: I ask because it's _probably_ unrelated, but https://crrev.com/487664 "Don't allow content scripts on the New Tab Page"

Comment: It depends in which context the posted code runs. If this is a background/event page and you use a new tab page *override*, they can communicate via runtime.onMessage and runtime.sendMessage. When you post a question about a chrome/web extension, always describe the exact context, manifest.json is also usually required for a precise answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's a background script. I edited the question, could you write a full answer? I do messages in different parts of the code, but it's not clear to me where should I send the message to if the tab isn't treated as a real tab.

Comment: What do you mean "not a real tab"? It's real tab but it also runs in the same internal context of the extension so chrome.runtime.onMessage in the new tab override will receive a message sent via chrome.runtime.sendMessage.